# Apply multiple aggregate functions on a list without using pandas

Tags: python, list, numpy, group-by, python-itertools

I have a list of rows, with two key columns and 6 value
columns.
I want to calculate the sum, mean, and max
of the value columns, based on lists of columns for each function,
grouped by the key columns, using `itertools.groupby`,
without using pandas.

```
columns = [ID, date, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6]
rows = [[1, date1, 1,     1,    1,   0,    0,  1],
        [1, date1, 1,     2,    0,   1,    0,  1],
        [2, date1, 1,     3,    0,   0,    1,  1], 
        [2, date1, 1,     3,    0,   0,    2,  1]]

ColSum = [row2, row6]
ColMean = [row1, row3]
ColMax = [row4, row5]
```

The result I expect to calculate:

```
rows_result = [[1, date1, 1,     3,  0.5,   1,    0,  2],
               [2, date1, 1,     6,    0,   0,    2,  2]]
```

My code:

```
for cols in ColSum:
  index = int(np.where(columns == cols)[0][0])
        
  for k, g in itertools.groupby(rows[:, index], operator.itemgetter(0,1)):
    res.append((list(k) +list(map(sum, zip(*[c[2:] for c in g])))))

for colm in colMean:
  index = int(np.where(columns == colm)[0][0])
    
  for k, g in itertools.groupby(rows[:, index], operator.itemgetter(0,1)):
    res.append((list(k) +list(map(sum, zip(*[c[2:] for c in g])))))
```

However, this doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you want to you by e.g. `ColSum = [row2, row6]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating each of the grouped column results separately while constructing
the results list is pretty complicated. After initial construction for `ColSum`,
you would have to edit each row-level element. It can be done, but I do not
think it fits with the spirit of functional programming.

Instead, the program below uses `ColFun` to set the function to be applied to
each of the columns (equivalent to row1 through row6). In the `for` loop,
it runs through each of the groups (like `(1, 'date1')`), while constructing
a list of the 6 value columns with the requested function application on the
column.

The result is appended to a list, which matches the (slightly edited) desired
result.

```
import itertools
import operator
import numpy as np

columns = ['ID', 'date', 'row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'row5', 'row6']
rows = [[1, 'date1', 1,     1,    1,   0,    0,  1],
        [1, 'date1', 1,     2,    0,   1,    0,  1],
        [2, 'date1', 1,     3,    0,   0,    1,  1], 
        [2, 'date1', 1,     3,    0,   0,    2,  1]]

ColSum = ['row2', 'row6']
ColMean = ['row1', 'row3']
ColMax = ['row4', 'row5']
ColFun = [np.mean, np.sum, np.mean, np.max, np.max, np.sum]
rows_result = [[1, 'date1', 1.0,   3,  0.5,   1,    0,  2],
               [2, 'date1', 1.0,   6,  0.0,   0,    2,  2]]

res = []
for k,g in itertools.groupby(rows, operator.itemgetter(0,1)):
    res.append(list(k) + [sum(map(z[0], z[1:])) for z in
        zip(ColFun, zip(*[c[2:] for c in g]))]
        )
print(res == rows_result)
# True
print(res)
# [[1, 'date1', 1.0, 3, 0.5, 1, 0, 2],
#  [2, 'date1', 1.0, 6, 0.0, 0, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer, it helped me a lot.